# method update is asynchronous?- unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

We know that the update method runs infinitely. I've a question, is the update method running in parallel or is it linear? if it is parallel, can it be changed to linear?

By parallel I mean that it is not necessary to finish executing all the code completely within the update method.

Comment: The Update method on a MonoBehavior is synchronous. It is called each frame and must return before further processing can continue. Now I gotta ask, what's the real issue you're trying to figure out?

Comment: I try to understand how it works to be careful with what I develop.

assumption: If the program is executed within 2 frames, then the update method is executed 2 times correct? What happens if the first execution of the update method takes much longer to finish than when the second frame execution begins? Does the execution of the second frame wait for the execution of the update of the first frame to execute?
According to what you comment if, once the execution of the first frame ends so it takes longer than one frame, the execution of the second frame begins recently.

Comment: The second link in the answer below has a nice diagram that may help to visualize it. All of the Update and LateUpdate calls in a frame must complete before the next frame can begin. If you spend too much time in the Update calls then your frame rate goes down.

Answer (score 0):

They are called serially, always on the main thread.

Useful links:

- [10000 Update() calls](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/)
- [Order of Execution for Event Functions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)